# What does two at (@) signs surrounding a string mean in a shell script?

Tags: shell, nixpkgs

For example,

```sh
# Execute the pre-hook.
export SHELL=@shell@
param1=@param1@
param2=@param2@
param3=@param3@
param4=@param4@
param5=@param5@
if test -n "@preHook@"; then
    . @preHook@
fi
```

For context, this is [from a shell script](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/0376334dde8ba130e6a53b308567a0838c6207c3/pkgs/stdenv/generic/setup.sh#L18) in [a commit from 2004 in the Nixpkgs repo](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/commit/01a1658c6b8cdf75ad87ea24d1f82bc6c17670d4); tried to see if this maybe a reference feature but string "*shell*" only occurs once (in a case-sensitive search) in the entire file.

Comment: Comments moved to an answer, thank you for the prodding to do so.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Appreciate your time for imparting these details!

Comment: BTW, there are some other `@foo@` examples out there that aren't shell-related at all; if my memory serves (it may not, it's been a lot of years) that's the same form CVS used to substitute things like last-change timestamps and revision numbers into source files that needed them, f/e.

Comment: (Looked it up, and I was wrong; that was `$foo$`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer by Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67349508/14122) is correct, insofar as there's no intrinsic meaning to the shell -- and `@foo@` is thus commonly used as a sigil. Insofar as you encountered this in nixpkgs, it provides some stdenv tools specifically for implementing this pattern.

As documented at https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-stdenv-functions, nixpkgs stdenv provides shell functions including `substitute`, `substituteAll`, `substituteInPlace` &c. which will replace `@foo@` values with the content of corresponding variables.

---

In the context of the linked commit, subsitutions of that form can be seen being performed in `pkgs/build-wrapper/gcc-wrapper/builder.sh`:

```sh
    sed \
        -e "s^@gcc@^$src^g" \
        -e "s^@out@^$out^g" \
        -e "s^@bash@^$SHELL^g" \
        -e "s^@shell@^$shell^g" \
        < $gccWrapper > $dst
```

...is replacing `@out@` with the value of `$out`, `@bash@` with the value of `$SHELL`, etc.

Comment: "as documented" ... see also [substituteAll in the stdenv chapter](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/doc/stdenv/stdenv.chapter.md#substituteall-infile-outfile-fun-substituteall). see also [makeSetupHook in trivial-builders.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix)

Answer (score 3):

The `@` symbol has no meaning to the shell -- it is a punctuation character that will pretty much never occur in any actual shell script.

This makes it a good choice to use for patterns in script templates -- the basic idea being that a simple search-and-replace process will be used (perhaps with a sed script as in the link you show) to rewrite the template into an actual shell script.  Every string of the form `@`*name*`@` in the template will be replaced by some other string related to the environment in which the script is being installed.